# Контроль регистра первого символа в QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, строки, qtcreator, символы

Нужно в форму LineEdit ввести текст, который обязательно должен начинаться с заглавной буквы.

Каким образом можно записать проверку (на регистр первой буквы), перевести в заглавный регистр (есть ф-я toapper(), но она не работает с классом QString) и в "автоматическом" режиме заменить самую первую букву формы LineEdit на заглавную?

Также не совсем понятно, какой сигнал нужно выбирать при переходе к слоту ( пробовал editingFinished() ):

[image: signal]

Я пытался сделать перевод в верхний регистр таким образом:

```
QString s[50] = ui -> lineEdit -> text();
QString str;
s[0] = str;
str = str.toUpper();
```

Но как дальше присвоить значение str форме LineEdit не совсем понял (да и подход, наверно, неправильный).

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `QLineEdit::setValidator(const QValidator *v)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите валидатор при помощи `setValidator`, в качестве валидатора можно использовать свой класс-наследник `QValidator` (он довольно просто создаётся), у него можно переопределить метод `fixup`, который исправит пользовательский ввод. Или можно просто использовать регулярное выражение при помощи `QRegExpValidator`, но тогда не получится исправлять ввод автоматически.